# Get multiple words using regular expression with space between them

Tags: javascript

I have the following

"Thi something the get lot"

I want to get the following with 3 character in JavaScript

1. Thi
2. The
3. Get
4. Lot

I'm tried

```
 /(\s[a-zA-Z]{3})|([a-zA-Z]{3}\s)|([a-zA-Z]{3})$/g
```

But with that I'll get the last 3 letter from "something"

Thank you for your help

Comment: try testing it here - regexpal.com

Comment: -_-" I already did, why you think i'm here asking this question

Answer (score 1):

You match all three letter words with this:

```
/(\b[a-z]{3}\b)/gi
```

The `\b` matches with a switch from letters to non-letters and vice versa, so there is no need to match spaces on either side. What's more, it will also detect words that have punctuation following it, like

> Hey, are you ill?

Will have following matches:

> Hey
>
> are
>
> you
>
> ill

Also, instead of matching `[a-zA-Z]`, you can use the `i` modifier in combination with just `[a-z]`.